# Array value changes if object value is changed

Tags: javascript, reference

The array changes its value even though it was pushed earlier

```
var original = 
[{
    a: 1,
    data: 
        { b: 'before' }
},
{
    a: 2,       
    data: 
        { b: 'before' }
}];

var arr1 = [];
var arr2 = [];


for(i=0; i<original.length; i++) {
    let value = original[i];

    //pushed earlier
    arr1.push(value);

    let newvalue = original[i];
    if (newvalue.data.b == "before") {
        newvalue.data.b = "after";
        arr2.push(newvalue);
    }
}

console.log("ARRAY 1 ");
console.log(arr1);
console.log("ARRAY 2 ");
console.log(arr2);
```

produces

```
ARRAY 1 
[ { a: 1, data: { b: 'after' } }, { a: 2, data: { b: 'after' } } ]
ARRAY 2
[ { a: 1, data: { b: 'after' } }, { a: 2, data: { b: 'after' } } ]
```

I am guessing this has something to do with how JS changes the value since it is being reference by the original array itself.

Whats the optimal solution in such cases where you have to retain the original array while use it to modify and create another array?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67546996/a-json-file-created-with-nodejs-holds-the-wrong-data/67547050#67547050 does this solve your question?

Comment: Or here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays and Objects in javascript are pass by reference by default.

If you want to avoid this behaviour, you could use [Object.assign](http://you%27ll%20have%20to%20use%20%60JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))%60%20here,) but that fails for deep copy of objects so you'll have to use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))` here,

```
let newvalue = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(original[i]));
```

```js
var original = [{
    a: 1,
    data: {
      b: 'before'
    }
  },
  {
    a: 2,
    data: {
      b: 'before'
    }
  }
];

var arr1 = [];
var arr2 = [];


for (i = 0; i < original.length; i++) {
  let value = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(original[i]));

  //pushed earlier
  arr1.push(value);

  let newvalue = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(original[i]));
  if (newvalue.data.b == "before") {
    newvalue.data.b = "after";
    arr2.push(newvalue);
  }
}

console.log("ARRAY 1 ");
console.log(arr1);
console.log("ARRAY 2 ");
console.log(arr2);
```

Comment: This works! But is it the most optimal/recommended way?

Comment: @AsgharMusani Yes it is, you could use libraries like lodash's `cloneDeep` if your object size/nesting is unpredictable - https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep

Answer (score -1):

You would use what is called the spread operator which creates a copy and allows you to modify it.
example:

```js
let newElement = 1;
const modifiedArray = [...oldArray, newElement];
```

There are also other javascript methods like `slice()` that will return a modified copy of an array.

Comment: They are mutating the object inside the array.  `[...oldArray]` only creates a copy of the array